# Mysql request cache

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have created a small php code the request from MySQL a count of specific table.

How can I compress that to a static page in order not to make the request each time the page loads?

Eg, can I convert it to a static HTML that refresh once every day?

Comment: You need to *cache* your query results, not *compress* them.  It will be helpful to tell us more about your operational environment

Answer (score 1):

Compressing means you reduce the size of storage which is needed to save or transfer something. But according to your question you want to cache the content. Caching means you temporarily store data which is expensive to generate, so that it can accessed more faster and using less ressources the next time. This *can* be combined with compressing. For example compressing the static page before they get saved, so that it will take less storage than without compression. But this will go deeper in detail than it looks like you're.

There are different methods and technologies for caching. Its depending on your application which one is the best. Generally a HTTP-Accelerator like varnish https://www.varnish-cache.org/ will be the fasteset one. Shortly explained, varnish will listen on port 80 and accept http-requests. Your webserver (for example nginx, apache, iis) will listen on another port (maybe 81). For every request varnish will look in his cache which can be on disk or in the ram. If the requested site is in the cache varnish will deliver them VERY fast in a few hundred ms or faster, depending on your app and infrastructure. When it's not already cached, he will fetch the page from your backend-server, save it in the cache for further requests and deliver it to the user. Generally this will be the same result than storing the content with php in static files, but much faster because using php costs time.

But such solutions can be difficult or maybe even inefficient when you have a lot of user-specific requests. For example when users can login, you can't cache those requests easilly: The page is different to every user, so maybe it beaks access-limitations to content. When you have such a scenario, it make sense to use varnish only for not-loggedin users.

But you should notice that this has nothing to do with a *MySQL* cache as you mentioned in the title! MySQL has as query-cache itself https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html which is a different thing. This will only cache the database-querys. There are other methods like this to cache parts of a page. Like xcache http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ it has a global storage where you can save data which will cost a lot of resources to generate.

Keep in mind that these things are on a different level than caching the whole page. They will speed-up your site but not as much as for example varnish could do it. Depending on your question it looks like that you want something like varnish. When I am wrong you should be more specific and edit your questions with details about the system where you want to introduce caching.